# Find the minimum value of $2a+ (1/a) + (1/2b) + b$, where a, b > 0

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Find the minimum value of $2a+ (1/a)  + (1/2b) + b$, where a, b > 0

**My approach:-**

Since a and b are positive numbers, I applied AM-GM inequality

$(2a+(1/a)+(1/2b)+b) /4$ ≥ $(2a\cdot (1/a)\cdot (1/2b)\cdot b) ^ {1/4} $

Giving me the answer as $4$

but the correct answer given in my textbook is $3\cdot \sqrt(2)$

I guess I am applying the inequality correctly, then what is the issue ?

Comment: The AM-GM inequality tells you, correctly, that the minimum value is greater than or equal to 4. But that's all it tells you.

Comment: Oh okay, I have not come across with such a question before where I need to check whether there is some other minimum value too , how shall I proceed then ?

Comment: AM-GM inequality says minimum of $4$ will be achieved when all quantities are equal. What happens when the four quantities in the inequality are equal? Is it possible?

Comment: First, split the sum into two parts, so you can minimise them separately. It should be obvious how to do this (you should have seen it yourself). Then you can use calculus.

Comment: But why cant all of them be equal to each other, why do we need to split the terms, also if I would have seen it, I wouldn't have posted it as a question

Comment: Oh Fin, Fin, you and all your questions! You have to put a bit of thought into them yourself, you know.

Comment: @TonyK I understand your point , that's why I always make it a point to put my approach of whatever information or knowledge I have to share with  kind people who help me guide through the right process

Answer (score 4):

AM-GM inequality applied to $(2a,1/a,1/2b,b)$ gives

$$2a+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2b}+b \ge 4 \tag{1}$$

where equality is to be achieved for $2a=1/a=1/2b=b$. Solving this gives $a=1/\sqrt{2}$ but does not give a unique/consistent value for $b$.

Conclusion is, AM-GM cannot be applied to all four quantities at once. However, since $a,b$ are independent positive quantities, one can safely apply AM-GM separately to $(2a,1/a)$ and $(1/2b,b)$.

$$2a+\frac{1}{a}\ge 2\sqrt{2}$$
where equality is achieved for $2a=1/a \Rightarrow a=1/\sqrt{2}$. Similarly
$$\frac{1}{2b}+b\ge \sqrt{2}$$
where equality is achieved for $1/2b=b \Rightarrow b=1/\sqrt{2}$.

Hence $2a+1/a + 1/2b+b$ is minimized for $a=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $b=1/\sqrt{2}$. At these values, the expression takes the value of
$$2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}=3\sqrt{2}$$
Indeed $3\sqrt{2}$ is larger than $4$ because our first inequation, $(1)$, still holds true.

Answer (score 2):

In the way you are applying AM-GM, the equality condition is not achievable. If applying AM-GM to find minimum, please be sure to check the values at which equality occurs. In this case there are no such values.

Alternatively, complete the square and rewrite it as -

$ \small \displaystyle 2a + \frac 1 a + b + \frac 1 {2b} = \left(\sqrt{2a} - \frac{1}{\sqrt a}\right)^2 + \left(\sqrt b - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2b}}\right)^2 + 3 \sqrt2$

The minimum value of the first two terms can be zero which occurs at $a = b = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$